# Many-to-many relationship with composite keys, extra column in Hibernate

Tags: java, foreign-keys, many-to-many, composite-primary-key, hibernate-annotations

I have 3 data table:
**Applications** {id_app, version, name} 
**Customers** {org_id, name} 
**Associations** {id_app, version, org_id, state}. 
Applications has a composite primary key (id_app, version), the primary key for Customers is org_id and Associations has a composite primary key (id_app, version, org_id).

In my java application I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Applications")
@IdClass(ApplicationId.class)
public class Application implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_APP", nullable = false)
    private String idApp;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false)
    private String version;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idPk.appPk", fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Association> custApps;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```
public class ApplicationId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String idApp;
    private String version;

    //hashcode and equals
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMERS")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORG_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer orgID;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="idPk.customerPk", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Association> custApps;

    //getters and setters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSOCIATIONS")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "idPk.appPk", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_APP")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "idPk.appPk", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "VERSION")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "idPK.customerPk", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORG_ID")) 
    })
public class Association implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private AssociationId idPk = new AssociationId();
    private String state;

    public Association() {
        super();
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public AssociationId getIdPk() {
        return idPk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Customer getCustomerPk() {
        return idPk.getCustomerPk();
    }

    @Transient
    public Application getAppPk() {
        return idPk.getAppPk();
    }

    @Column(name = "STATE")
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    //setters , hashCode and equals
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class AssociationId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Application appPk;
    private Customer customerPk;

    // here is the problem ?
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "ID_APP", referencedColumnName = "ID_APP"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "VERSION", referencedColumnName = "VERSION") })
    public Application getAppPk() {
        return appPk;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="ORG_ID")
    public Customer getCustomerPk() {
        return customerPk;
    }

    //setter, hashCode and equals
}
```

What are the correct annotation? The relationship is many to many between Application and Customers and I create the Association table for that and for the extra column "state". 
Now I receive this **error**: A Foreign key refering sla.model.Application from sla.model.Association has the wrong number of column. should be 2 .

Please help.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-associations

Comment: This is not my situation, I tried something similar but it doesn't work because I have also a composite primary key on Application table

Comment: Read again. The section I linked to says: *In the following example, the PersonAddress entity identifier is formed of two @ManyToOne associations*. That's **exactly** what you have. The examples above show various other solutions, all having a ManyToOne association as part of the identifier.

Comment: So you suggest to delete @JoinColumn from AssociationId class. And that's all?

Comment: Now I receive this error: A Foreign key refering sla.model.Application from sla.model.Association has the wrong number of column. should be 2

Comment: No. I suggest you red the various solutions presented in the documentation, and choose the one you prefer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Done. I change the following: 
In Association class:

```
@AssociationOverrides({
@AssociationOverride(name = "idPk.appPk", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_APP", referencedColumnName = "ID_APP"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "VERSION", referencedColumnName = "VERSION") }),
@AssociationOverride(name = "idPK.customerPk", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORG_ID")) 
})
```